# xsl xml batching

Tags: xml, xslt, batch-file

I need to implement some kind of batching in an xsl mapping.
Example:

Input:

```
    <FinTrans_Dinas_FF xmlns="http://MH.ESB.Dinas.Schemas.FinTrans_FF.FinTrans_FF">
        <Line xmlns="">
            <Header>
                <DocumentDate>03022011</DocumentDate>
                <Reference>71013849</Reference>
            </Header>
            <Item>
                <PostingKey>01</PostingKey>
                <AccountNumber>0000560141</AccountNumber>
                <AmountInDocumentCurrency>/</AmountInDocumentCurrency>
                <AmountInLocalCurrency>21,42</AmountInLocalCurrency>
            </Item>
        </Line>
        <Line xmlns="">
            <Header>
                <DocumentDate>03022011</DocumentDate>
                <Reference>71013849</Reference>
            </Header>
            <Item>
                <PostingKey>01</PostingKey>
                <AccountNumber>0000560141</AccountNumber>
                <AmountInDocumentCurrency>/</AmountInDocumentCurrency>
                <AmountInLocalCurrency>21,42</AmountInLocalCurrency>
            </Item>
        </Line>
        <Line xmlns="">
            <Header>
                <DocumentDate>03022011</DocumentDate>
                <Reference>77777777</Reference>
            </Header>
            <Item>
                <PostingKey>02</PostingKey>
                <AccountNumber>0000560141</AccountNumber>
                <AmountInDocumentCurrency>/</AmountInDocumentCurrency>
                <AmountInLocalCurrency>21,42</AmountInLocalCurrency>
            </Item>
        </Line>
    </FinTrans_Dinas_FF>
```

Now I need to create a record foreach unique line (key = Reference).
So in my input message I have 2 unique records:

```
Reference = 71013849
Reference = 77777777
```

So my output file needs to look like this (simplified it a bit):

```
       <Trans>
        <Record>
            <Lines>
                <Line>
                    <Reference>71013849</Reference>
                    <Account>Account1</Account>
                </Line>
                <Line>
                    <Reference>71013849</Reference>
                    <Account>Account2</Account>
                </Line>
            </Lines>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <Lines>
                <Line>
                    <Reference>77777777</Reference>
                    <Account>Account3</Account>
                </Line>
            </Lines>
        </Record>
    </Trans>
```

So as you can see my input file contains 3 'Line' items, my output contains 2 'Record' items (with inside the Record node the lines). Obviously inside the 'Lines/Line' item there should be more data, but I simplified it for this example.

Anyone knows the best way to solve this? (In XSLT 1.0)

Thx very much!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution and explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kLineByRef" match="Line"
          use="Header/Reference"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "Line[generate-id()
       =
        generate-id(key('kLineByRef', Header/Reference)[1])
       ]">
  <Record>
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('kLineByRef', Header/Reference)"/>
  </Record>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<FinTrans_Dinas_FF xmlns="http://MH.ESB.Dinas.Schemas.FinTrans_FF.FinTrans_FF">
    <Line xmlns="">
        <Header>
            <DocumentDate>03022011</DocumentDate>
            <Reference>71013849</Reference>
        </Header>
        <Item>
            <PostingKey>01</PostingKey>
            <AccountNumber>0000560141</AccountNumber>
            <AmountInDocumentCurrency>/</AmountInDocumentCurrency>
            <AmountInLocalCurrency>21,42</AmountInLocalCurrency>
        </Item>
    </Line>
    <Line xmlns="">
        <Header>
            <DocumentDate>03022011</DocumentDate>
            <Reference>71013849</Reference>
        </Header>
        <Item>
            <PostingKey>01</PostingKey>
            <AccountNumber>0000560141</AccountNumber>
            <AmountInDocumentCurrency>/</AmountInDocumentCurrency>
            <AmountInLocalCurrency>21,42</AmountInLocalCurrency>
        </Item>
    </Line>
    <Line xmlns="">
        <Header>
            <DocumentDate>03022011</DocumentDate>
            <Reference>77777777</Reference>
        </Header>
        <Item>
            <PostingKey>02</PostingKey>
            <AccountNumber>0000560141</AccountNumber>
            <AmountInDocumentCurrency>/</AmountInDocumentCurrency>
            <AmountInLocalCurrency>21,42</AmountInLocalCurrency>
        </Item>
    </Line>
</FinTrans_Dinas_FF>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<Record>
   <Line>
      <Header>
         <DocumentDate>03022011</DocumentDate>
         <Reference>71013849</Reference>
      </Header>
      <Item>
         <PostingKey>01</PostingKey>
         <AccountNumber>0000560141</AccountNumber>
         <AmountInDocumentCurrency>/</AmountInDocumentCurrency>
         <AmountInLocalCurrency>21,42</AmountInLocalCurrency>
      </Item>
   </Line>
   <Line>
      <Header>
         <DocumentDate>03022011</DocumentDate>
         <Reference>71013849</Reference>
      </Header>
      <Item>
         <PostingKey>01</PostingKey>
         <AccountNumber>0000560141</AccountNumber>
         <AmountInDocumentCurrency>/</AmountInDocumentCurrency>
         <AmountInLocalCurrency>21,42</AmountInLocalCurrency>
      </Item>
   </Line>
</Record>
<Record>
   <Line>
      <Header>
         <DocumentDate>03022011</DocumentDate>
         <Reference>77777777</Reference>
      </Header>
      <Item>
         <PostingKey>02</PostingKey>
         <AccountNumber>0000560141</AccountNumber>
         <AmountInDocumentCurrency>/</AmountInDocumentCurrency>
         <AmountInLocalCurrency>21,42</AmountInLocalCurrency>
      </Item>
   </Line>
</Record>
```

**Explanation**: **[Muenchian method for grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.

When the number of records and different key values is significant, this is the most efficient known grouping method.

Comment: Wow, thx. I first did this solution with a loop foreach line and checked if the previous reference was the same then skip the loop. But the performance was really bad. Thx a lot for this solution!